# Read file in text mode but also count raw bytes in Python?

Tags: python, csv

I'd like to read a file in text mode line-wise, but at the same time I'd like to insert an intermediate step which works on bytes data and basically counts the bytes read so far.

Is there a good way in the standard library to achieve that (without manually opening in bytes mode, searching for newlines, encoding, ...)? At the end I need a text reading object (being used in the CSV reader) which additionally has a byte counter.

Comment: You want to know how many bytes were read? Do you know the encoding of the file?

Comment: Are you just looking for the `tell` method of file objects?

Comment: Yes, I will specify the encoding as usual when opening the text file. The `.tell()` method is disabled for some reason due to buffering or so. All I need is reading the CSV while counting the number of raw bytes read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Python 2

`csv` module works with binary files in Python 2 therefore you could just call `file.tell()` method to get the current byte offset in the file.

#### Python 3

You can't use `text_file.tell()` (`TextIOBase` instance) -- it is documented to return an opaque number that may not correspond to the actual byte position.

If it is acceptable for your use case to get the byte offset with ± bufsize precision then:

```
file = open(filename, 'rb') # open in binary mode
text_file = io.TextIOWrapper(file, newline='') # text mode
# pass text_file to csv module
byte_offset = file.tell() # get position ± buffering
```

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that you can disable buffering by passing 0 to `open`'s third argument, `buffering`.

Comment: @roippi: `TextIOWrapper` is documented to work only with buffered files. Passing an unbuffered file may lead to wrong results today or in the future.